# Polynomial divisibility impossibility

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I have a textbook which is known to have typos. One of the exercise questions says

Given that $f(x)$ is a polynomial with real coefficients. If there are distinct real numbers $a,b,c$ such that the remainder of $f(x)$ are $a,b,c$ when $f$ is divided by $(x-a),(x-b),(x-c)$ respectively, prove that $f(x)$ has the factor $(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)$.

I feel this result cannot possibly be true. What should this result actually say?

Answer (score 3):

Hint:  the polynomial $f(x)-x$ must have $a,b,c$ as roots.

Comment: _Right, that's about it..._

Comment: This just shows that when divided by $(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)$ the remainder is $x$. This shows that $f(x)$ does not have that as a factor...

Comment: @1-___- Indeed, this shows that $f(x)=x + q(x)(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)$ for some arbitrary polynomial $q(x)$. It was meant to answer the `I feel this result cannot possibly be true. What should this result actually say?` part of your question.

Comment: Oh I see. So $f(x)$ should have been replaced with $f(x)-x$. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Slightly more generally, take $g(x)=(x-a_1)\cdots(x-a_k)$
with distinct $a_1,\ldots,a_k$. If the remainder of dividing $f$
by $x-a_i$ is always $a_i$, then the remainder of dividing $f$ by $g$
is $x$ (at least if $k\ge2$).